# How do you cast a list of list of one single string as a list of lists with individual integer values

Tags: python, string, list

I have an issue where I have some data giving me a list of lists such as;

x = [['128, 0, 0, 508, 1023, 516, 510, 509, 515'], ['135, 0, 23, 308, 1023, 326, 330, 649, 526']]

I am looking to take the 6th element of each list and store it as an integer in another list such that I should be able to iterate through as many inside lists and get the 6th value into another list so it is populated with integer values.

How can I achieve this?

I have currently tried the attempted solution below, however this does not work since split is not an attribute.

y = [int(elem) for elem in x.split(',') ]

Comment: Just to make sure, each list in `x` only contains a single string that merely looks like a list?

Comment: You need to dive deeper into each item. If there is only ever one value, this should work: `[int(elem[0].split(', ')[5]) for elem in x]`

Comment: @flakes is right, his code works. And it's for sure faster than using a for loop and append the value to a list

Answer (score 1):

First with :

```
y = [e[0].split(",") for e in x]
```

You got :
[['128', ' 0', ' 0', ' 508', ' 1023', ' 516', ' 510', ' 509', ' 515'],
['135', ' 0', ' 23', ' 308', ' 1023', ' 326', ' 330', ' 649', ' 526']]

Then  :

```
[int(e[6]) for e in y]
```

Give you : [510, 330]

Comment: e[6] is the seventh item

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that you are trying to split the entire list of lists x, which is not possible because `split()` is a string method, and x is a list of lists. To achieve your goal, you should iterate through the sublists and then split and convert the 6th element of each sublist to an integer. Here's a corrected version of your code:

```
x = [['128, 0, 0, 508, 1023, 516, 510, 509, 515'], ['135, 0, 23, 308, 1023, 326, 330, 649, 526']]

# Initialize an empty list to store the 6th elements as integers
result = []

for sublist in x:
    # Split the sublist by ',' and take the 6th element, then convert it to an integer
    sixth_element = int(sublist[0].split(',')[5])
    result.append(sixth_element)

print(result)
```